# Display many charts with data of the same source javascript ( map (key,value) )

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a map of this form

```
 Object{485:Array[4],2072:Array[4],9665:Array[3]...}
```

I would like to display a chart per key.

I have an example which is similar to what i'm  looking for and i tried to display my values in many charts  : In this example, my key is : car_id

First step : sort my array to get a map with my keys. It works fine. But the second one is not working... I would like to display a chart per data based on car_id and per panel bootstrap... 
What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you

```
<html >

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript --><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.0/Chart.min.js"></script>



<script src=" https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<body >
    <div >
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading without title</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>var json = {
    'cars': [{
        "car_id": "1",
        "price": "925",
        "full_option": "EEEE"
        }, {
        "car_id": "1",
        "price": "990",
        "full_option": "DDDDD"
        }, {
        "car_id": "2",
        "price": "500",
        "full_option": "FFF"
        }, {
        "car_id": "2",
        "price": "900",
        "full_option": "GGGGGGG"
        }, {
        "car_id": "4",
        "price": "900",
        "full_option": "JJJ"
    }]
};


var car_array = json.cars.reduce((prev, t, index, arr) => {
    if (typeof prev[t.car_id] === 'undefined') {
        prev[t.car_id] = [];
    }
    prev[t.car_id].push(t);
    return prev;
}, {});



Object.keys(car_array).forEach(i => {
    var array_of_cars_with_same_id = car_array[i];
    for (var i=0; i<=array_of_cars_with_same_id.length-1;i++){
        console.log(array_of_cars_with_same_id[i].price);

        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: [array_of_cars_with_same_id[i].full_option],
                datasets: [{
                    label: '# of Votes',
                    data: [array_of_cars_with_same_id[i].price]
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero:true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });

    }
    console.log("AAAAAAAAAAAAA");
});




</script>
```

Comment: Is `Object{485:Array[4],2072:Array[4],9665:Array[3]...}` supposed to be the same thing as the variable `json`? Is the code `Object.keys(car_array).forEach(i => {` what you are referring to with `the second one is not working`?  What is exactly is not working?

Comment: @whipdancer   Object{485:Array[4],2072:Array[4],9665:Array[3]...}  is not the same thing as the variable json. The variable json is a small example similar to the "Object{485:Array[4],2072:Array[4],9665:Array[3]...}" which is too big. That's why i have choosen a simpler example. The not working part is the part supposed to create a chart per key (in the for loop ). I got only one chart for all keys together..

Comment: Please provide `Object{485:Array[4],2072:Array[4],9665:Array[3]...} ' - a small version. 3 keys or something similar, so that there is a representative sample - or structure your sample so that it exactly mimics the data you are dealing with.

Comment: @whipdancer The variable ' car_array' is very representative. If you make a 'console.log( car_array)' you get : 'Object{1:Array[2],2:Array[2],4:Array[1]}'. the variable 'car_array' is a reduce version of the variable 'json'. When I say reduce in fact, it's just the Objects cars with same car_id put together

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to make sure the the items in the array `"car_id": "1","price": "925", "full_option": "EEEE"` are the same key names and value types to expect - not how it renders in console.log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code.

First, you are only using a single `canvas` element.  Each chart needs its own canvas element. Because of this every chart you add simply renders on top of the prior chart.

At a minimum, you have to give each item a new canvas. You could change your code to accomplish that.

Change the root element for the charts to a basic `<div>` element that you will append the charts to.

```
<div class="panel-body">
   <div id="chart-holder"></div>
</div>
```

I would create a variable to hold the cart count, and the root element.

```
var chart_holder = $('#chart-holder');
var chart_count = 0;
```

Change the `for loop` to use these new variables.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= car_type.length - 1; i++) {
    chart_holder.append('<canvas id="myChart' + chart_count + '" width="400" height="400"></canvas>')

    var ctx = $("#myChart" + chart_count);
    var data = [];
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: [car_type[i].full_option],
        datasets: [{
          label: '# of Votes',
          data: [car_type[i].price]
        }]
      },
      options: chart_opts
    });
    chart_count++;
}
```

This will create a new chart for each object in each array.
I created [a fiddle to demonstrate](https://jsfiddle.net/whipdancer/nsgjgmro/).

Based on the data, however, I would recommend a different approach.  I would create a single chart per unique key, rather than a chart for every element.

You would need to parse each array to pull out labels and data for each chart. Here is an example that would get that data out of each array. There is a variable to capture the data for the chart and the labels for the chart.

```
var car_data = [], car_labels = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= car_type.length - 1; i++) {
    car_data.push(car_type[i].price);
    car_labels.push(car_type[i].full_option);
}
```

We can pass `car_data` and `car_labels` to the Chart.js initialization.

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: car_labels,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Car Type ' + ct,
      data: car_data
    }]
  },
  options: chart_opts
});
```

Here is a [fiddle to demonstrate a single chart per car_id](https://jsfiddle.net/whipdancer/nuu1r3xm/).

Comment: Thank you, the second way works just like i was looking for ( a single chart per car_id). But in fact by this way , I won't be able display in my html code one single chart per car_id by "panel". I 'm using angular at work and is it possible to loop through the "div class="panel panel-default" with ng-repeat like this " chart in chart_holder" ? In clear how can I get an array from chart_holder to make a loop with ? I don't know if what i want is understandable. If not l'll try an other way to display my charts using what you show me. Thank you

Comment: You might want to consider a custom directive that holds the chart.  I'm still new to Angular so I can't give you much help on that part.